# Spring Boot AutoConfig for Repository in another module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I converted my project into a spring boot application. The problem I have met is the model/repo  module is not a sub package of the `main` method package. When I annotate `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in the `main` method class, it can not pick up all the repo class which I annotate with `@Repository` in a different module.

From Spring boot [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-spring-data-repositories), it says

> same package (or a sub-package) of your @EnableAutoConfiguration
>   class.

Is there a way I don't need to put repo as the same of a sub package of the `@EnableAutoConfigration` class

Comment: Add a `@EnableJpaRepositories` and tell it which packages to scan.

Comment: I am using spring-data-neo4j, this `@EnableJpaRepositories` will works for my case?

Comment: @jasonfungsing You're in good company with M. Deinum ;-)

Comment: I assumed you used JPA (you didn't mention neo4j) you should then use [`@EnableNeo4jRepositories`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/config/EnableNeo4jRepositories.html) instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry for this. I tried with `@EnableNeo4jRepositories`, but seems spring still can not find all the repos. the neo4j stuff I have put into a different module, is this causing the problem?

Comment: You should put the classes it should scan into this annotation. The `@EnableNeo4jRepositories` must be on a `@Configuration` class which is detected by a `@ComponentScan` or loaded in another way. Just putting it somewhere and expecting magic to happen isn't going work. I suggest putting it in the same class as the `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.